# EF Core NotMapped Getter with logic and using navigation properties - lazy-loading is not supported for detached entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model `Activity` which has some navigation properties.

I'm using lazy loading proxies to fetch all of the properties when using EF.

The NotMapped property `Status` uses the navigation property `ApprovalStatus`.

When fetching activities with LINQ condition of where the status is true it throws an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning:
>   An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'ApprovalStatus' on
>   detached entity of type 'ActivityProxy'. Lazy-loading is not supported
>   for detached entities or entities that are loaded with
>   'AsNoTracking()'.'

The model:

```
public class Activity {

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Approver> ApprovalStatus {get; set;}


    [NotMapped]
    public bool? Status {
        get {
            if (ApprovalStatus.Any(x => ...) return false;
            if (ApprovalStatus.All(x => ...) return true;

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The query i'm trying to perform:

```
applicationDbContext.Activities.Where(a => a.Status == true);
```

But if i'm converting the activities to list before the condition, it works.

```
applicationDbContext.Activities.ToList().Where(a => a.Status == true);
```

Comment: what's the declaration of Activities pls ?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is EF Core 2.x. I would recommend avoiding this type of query expression as automatic query evaluation changed in EF Core 3 to deter people from relying on it. I suspect that there are also buggy edge cases like what you have encountered where the client evaluation being done thinks the entity is detached.

Performance-wise, relying on lazy loading will hurt in the long run. One option you might consider to centralize rules like Status would be to reflect them as expressions/funcs in the domain.  This works with Boolean expressions so your "Status" check would need to be arranged to assert a particular combination:

```
public class Activity {

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Approver> ApprovalStatus {get; set;}

    public static Func<Activity, bool> IsApproved() {
       return (Activity a) => (a.ApprovalStatus.All(x => ...) 
           && !a.ApprovalStatus.Any(x => ...);

    public static Func<Activity, bool> IsRejected() {
       return (Activity a) => (!a.ApprovalStatus.All(x => ...) 
           || a.ApprovalStatus.Any(x => ...);

    }
}
```

then when consuming:

```
applicationDbContext.Activities.Where(Activity.IsApproved());
```

You can still have the unmapped property for lazy evaluation in code:

```
[NotMapped]
public bool? Status
{
    get 
    { 
        if(IsApproved().Invoke(this))
            return true;
        if(IsRejected().Invoke(this))
            return false;
        return null;
    }
}
```

A caveat of this approach is that with your `Where` clauses you cannot easily negate or compose extra OR conditions.. For instance the following does not work:

```
applicationDbContext.Activities.Where(!Activity.IsApproved());
```

I had a bit of a dig around to see if there was a way to get it so the expression could be something like:

```
applicationDbContext.Activities.Where(x => x.IsApproved());
```

via a static extension method to return an expression, but I wasn't able to get anything to work. There may be some Func/Expression black magic out there that would work and actually make it through Linq2Entity, but even if so, I'd expect it to look quite hideous.

The best option IMO is to write the expressions as you need to with the properties available.  I.e.:

```
applicationDbContext.Activities.Where(a => (a.ApprovalStatus.All(x => ...) 
       && !a.ApprovalStatus.Any(x => ...)
       // ...
);
```

It might be nice to be able to reuse expressions, but the above would be the most flexible and best performing option.

Comment: I can't find the proper syntax to mix IsApproved with extra boolean conditions inside an Any: ```applicationDbContext.Activities.Any(a => Activity.IsApproved() && ...)``` ? chaining the 'Any' like this is not correct syntactically : ```applicationDbContext.Activities.Any(Activity.IsApproved()).Any(a => ...)```

Comment: No, you won't be able to chain off that expression inside the `Any`. Your best bet in that case is to build your expression inside the `Any` using the raw data fields/relationships. The expression properties can help simplify very common checks, but only provided those checks are complete in-of-themselves.